# How to get the intro image of a joomla article

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am trying to customize the the category list of my website. So I have a menu option that shows the list of all article is a certain category.
In this list I would like to show the into image of the article too. But unfortunately I cannot find the path of this intro image of each article to put it in the '' tag.

This code takes the first image in the article. Which is not what I want.

```
<?php
$text = $article->introtext;
if(preg_match('/<\s*img[^>]+>/Ui', $text, $matches)){

   $image=$matches[0];
   $text = str_replace($image,'',$text);
}
if ($matches) {
$image = str_replace('img src="','img width="150px" src="/demo/persianlondon/',$image);
$image = str_replace("caption","", $image);
echo '' . $image . '';
}
else {echo '<img width="150px" src="http://goo.gl/k47rNN" class="defaultArticleImage" />';}
?>
```

So I need to get the intro image url and set it for `$image`.
Any idea to do it?

Comment: Good question for http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @GDP I didnt know there is an StackExchange for Joomla. However it seems no one is there.

Comment: all the SE sites are maintained by their members around the world....someone will eventually get to you question.  :)

Comment: The intro image is not inside the article text, it is in the images field. You need to simply use the same code you would use for showing it in an article, which involves json_decoding the image data.  I believe there  may already be a jlayout to manage a lot of this for you, but just look in the code for category blog and modify what is there .

Answer (score 0):

If you are talkin about blog view of a category, this code will write out the intro image filename with path, if you put it in file:

**jroot/component/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php** or in the template overrided blog.php file.

```
$article_items = $this->get('lead_items');
foreach ($article_items as $item) {
  $imageObj = json_decode($item->images);
  echo $imageObj->image_intro;
}
```

other variables of **$imageObj**:

```
stdClass Object
 (
   [image_intro] => 
   [float_intro] => 
   [image_intro_alt] => 
   [image_intro_caption] => 
   [image_fulltext] => 
   [float_fulltext] => 
   [image_fulltext_alt] => 
   [image_fulltext_caption] => 
 )
```